# Python subprocess get output

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have a python script to run a secondary python script, using subprocess module.
I want to capture the second python script output and keep it alive after I close my main python script.
I want to wait for a certain prompt in the second python script then stop the execution of my main script.
problem is that I'm not seeing the output in my loop.

My main script:

```
command = f'start /D C:\MyFolder python adapter.py -t \"UMB\" -d \"COM2\"'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
while True:    
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        print(output, end='')
```

also, I need the second python script to run from its folder "MyFolder"
please help, thanks!

edit:
I want to mention that I need the other python script to run in a dedicated terminal for the "user" to view it as it goes through the automation.
I chagned my code to

```
command = f'python adapter.py -t \"UMB\" -d \"COM2\"'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, cwd=os.path.dirname(r'C:\MyFolder'))
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readlines()
    if output:
        print(output, end='')
```

and still get empty strings

Comment: What do you mean by "run from its folder"? Are you looking for the `cwd=` keyword argument to `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: @tripleee Yes I have updated the question, please take a quick look. thanks!

Comment: I can't see why you would run `os.path.dirname` on the `cwd=` value; it will cause it to break if your current working directory is not on the C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code.

At first, the start command is generally used in a command prompt on Windows, but it is unnecessary when using subprocess.Popen().

Secondly, you should set the working directory using the cwd parameter in subprocess.Popen().

I would also recommend that you use stdout=subprocess.PIPE to capture your subprocess's output.

In case this isn't enough help or need clarifications, feel free to comment on this answer

Edit: considering your edits, you actually should use the start command to run the script in a dedicated terminal.

Here is what you can change:

```
import subprocess
import os

script_path = r'C:\MyFolder\adapter.py'

command = f'start cmd /K python {script_path} -t "UMB" -d "COM2"'

working_directory = r'C:\MyFolder'

process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, cwd=working_directory)
```

Note: You may need to add a time.sleep(1) to make sure that the new terminal has properly started. Also, cmd /K is not sure to work, but it is worth trying. Notify me for any failures and other challenges.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping!
I want to view the subprocess in a dedicated terminal and still read the output.
* First: I removed the start /D command.
* Second: I set the cwd paramter.
*Thirdly: still setting the stdout to subprocess.PIPE will result in empty string.
I am confident that my adapter.py prints becuase I have used it

Comment: I have updated my question, please brielfy look at the "edit" tag